# TensorFlow error on training Iris CSV data with softmax model

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

I justed started learning Tensorflow, I want to trained Iris CSV data with softmax model that my code was copied from [softmax.py](https://github.com/backstopmedia/tensorflowbook/blob/master/chapters/04_machine_learning_basics/softmax.py)

Here is my code

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4,3]), name="weights")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]), name="bias")

def readCSV(batch_size, file_name, record_defaults):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([file_name])

    reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    # decode_csv will convert a Tensor from type string (the text line) in
    # a tuple of tensor columns with the specified defaults, which also
    # sets the data type for each column
    decoded = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

    # batch actually reads the file and loads "batch_size" rows in a single tensor
    return tf.train.shuffle_batch(decoded,
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  capacity=batch_size * 50,
                                  min_after_dequeue=batch_size)

def inputs():
    filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../assets/dataset/iris.data")
    sepalLen, sepalWidth, petalLen, petalWidth, label = readCSV(100, filename, [[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[""]])


    labelNumber = tf.to_int32(
        tf.argmax(
            tf.to_int32(
                tf.stack(
                    [
                        tf.equal(label, ['Iris-setosa']),
                        tf.equal(label, ['Iris-versicolor']),
                        tf.equal(label, ['Iris-virginica'])
                    ]
                )
            ),
            0
        )
    )
    features = tf.transpose(tf.stack([sepalLen, sepalWidth, petalLen, petalWidth]))

    return features, labelNumber

def combine_inputs(X):
    return tf.matmul(X, W) + b

def inference(X):
    return tf.nn.softmax(combine_inputs(X))

def loss(X,Y):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=combine_inputs(X), labels=Y))

def train(total_loss):
    return tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(total_loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    X, Y = inputs()

    total_loss = loss(X, Y)
    train_op = train(total_loss)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run([train_op])
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("loss=", sess.run([total_loss]))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

iris data was downloaded from [iris data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris)

I use `python 3.6.2`,`tensorflow 1.3.0` on `windows 8.1 64bit`

When I run my script, I got below error:

> 2017-10-27 17:51:01.458997: W
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX in structions, but
>   these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU
>   computations. 2017-10-27 17:51:01.459123: W
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 i nstructions, but
>   these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU
>   computations. loss= [array([[ -3.07333539e-05,   1.91666477e-05,
>   1.15666444e-05],
>          [  1.02666581e-05,  -1.33334174e-06,  -8.93334254e-06],
>          [ -7.61333431e-05,   2.91666493e-05,   4.69666520e-05],
>          [ -3.16333317e-05,   8.46666080e-06,   2.31666618e-05]], dtype=float32)] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1327, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1306, in _run_fn
>       status, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\contextlib.py",
>   line 88, in **exit**
>       next(self.gen)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py",
>   line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
>       pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status)) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError:
>   RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed
>   and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 49)
>            [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]( shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "d:/workspace/tensorflow-study/chapter02：model/softmax.py", line 124,
>   in 
>       sess.run([train_op])   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 895, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1124, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1321, in _do_run
>       options, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1340, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError:
>   RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed
>   and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 49)
>            [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]( shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]
>
> Caused by op 'shuffle_batch', defined at:   File
>   "d:/workspace/tensorflow-study/chapter02：model/softmax.py", line 115,
>   in 
>       X, Y = inputs()   File "d:/workspace/tensorflow-study/chapter02：model/softmax.py", line 53,
>   in inputs
>       sepalLen, sepalWidth, petalLen, petalWidth, label = readCSV(100, filename, [[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[""]])   File
>   "d:/workspace/tensorflow-study/chapter02：model/softmax.py", line 35,
>   in readCSV
>       min_after_dequeue=batch_size)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py",
>   line 1220, in shuffle_batch
>       name=name)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py",
>   line 791, in _shuffle_batch
>       dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py",
>   line 457, in dequeue_many
>       self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)   File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py",
>   line 1342, in _queue_dequeue_many_v2
>       timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 767, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2630, in create_op
>       original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1204, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue
>   '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient
>   elements (requested 100, current size 49)
>            [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]( shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]

I got only one "loss=" output, How could I fix this problem.

Thank a lot.